# iOS - Parse Login - Change Button Title

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uibutton, pfloginviewcontroller

I can not change the title of the button Sign Up of the screen Log In.

The `self` is `PFLogInViewController`.

```
self.logInView?.signUpButton?.setTitle("Test new String", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I changed of other button, the same code. It works.

```
self.logInView?.logInButton?.setTitle("Entrar", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.logInView?.passwordForgottenButton?.setTitle("Esqueceu a Senha?", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParseUI uses internationalization: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/internationalization/

So maybe you should use localization to change the title as in the code implementation they maybe change the title even if you set it.

Stackoverflow thread about this subject:
[Localization of ParseUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291909/localization-of-parseui)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I created ParseUI.string solve my problem. But the setTitle of Sign Up Button do not work.